# Generate Column and Line Charts Procedurally

Tags: python, modifiers, geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm new to Blender and wanted some help with creating column charts and line charts, like you would in Excel.

**The need to be procedural**

I have hundreds of values for some charts, and altering each value individually would be a huge task! As such, I want to determine the values by importing or pasting values into Blender, in bulk, by importing data from Excel somehow (e.g. copying and pasting, using a script, etc).

**Animation**

I'd like the charts to animate, e.g. the columns of the column chart increase from 0 to their proper heights in an ease-in, ease-out manner, then remain stationary. I'd like the line of the line chart to zip from the left to the right in an ease-in, ease-out way too.

**Scaling to fit the size of the bounding box**

If there's a way to scale it to fit within a box of a given size (i.e. to fit it within given dimensions), that would be great too! Below is an image in Excel of exactly the kind of thing I want to recreate, with an axis, lines for ease of comparison, and columns/a line, all of which fit inside a bounding box. If the bounding box was scaled, I would like the rest of the graph to scale proportionately as well.

I've tried looking at array modifier and geometry node tutorials, but haven't found something which creates this functionality. I'd be incredibly grateful if someone could let me know how to do this!

[image]

Comment: and what did u try so far? at least you should post a blend file with e.g. a geometry nodes try you did. This site is for ONE specific problem only, not for a whole tutorial. So you should ask the one problem you have, e.g. how can i animate a column from 0 to 5? You can open as many questions as you like, but you shouldn't ask for tutorials. Maybe blenderartists.org is more suitable for these kind of questions.